# How to install PEAR on Mac

Tags: php, macos, pear

I have Mac 10.5.8, trying to install PEAR.

I believe at pear.php.net any version of Mac > 10.4 does not include PEAR in it.

Not sure if this is true or not, but when I go to the terminal and type in

```
pear -V or which pear or pear config-show
```

I get nothing- no error or messages. I guess I can assume I don't have pear install?

So then I tried in the terminal app:

```
$ curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear | php
```

I get the following error message:

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

Can someone give me steps to installing PEAR.

Thank you,

Ken

Answer (score 0):

Try [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) or [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/downloads), they both come with PEAR.

Comment: I already have MAMP installed. How do I check that PEAR is also installed.

Answer (score 0):

At the terminal, you just need to type:

```
curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear > go-pear.php
sudo php -q go-pear.php
```

Then you'll have to edit your php.ini and change the value of include_path

I followed this page and it worked correctly.

http://clickontyler.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-install-pear-in-mac-os-x-leopard/